# gwt-phonegap FileReader not working (iOS)

Tags: ios, cordova, gwt, phonegap-build

I am trying to read a file from an `iOS` device using `gwt-phonegap` (a wrapper for `cordova/phonegap` to ease usage within a GWT app).
As per tutorial (https://code.google.com/p/gwt-phonegap/wiki/FileModule) I need to request the filesystem first, then get the file entry of the file i want to read, and finally create a reader, register the onload callback, and call `reader.readAsText(fileEntry);`.

Everything works fine, except that the handler is never called back.

I also registered all other callbacks - none of them is called. That's odd. At least the on error callback should have been called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the gwt-phonegap.
Reading through the documentation of Cordova I noticed that the original Cordova version of `readAsText` requires a file not a file entry, however, the gwt-phonegap version of `readAsText` takes a file entry instead. This looked weird. So I checked the code of FileReaderJsImpl which is the actual implementation of the gwt-phonegap wrapper. And indeed, the file entry is used directly, which is wrong.
I copied the class and replaced the `readAsText0` operation with the following fix which solved the issue for `readAsText` (`readAsDataUrl`requires a similar fix):

```
private native void readAsText0(JavaScriptObject entry) /*-{
    var that = this;

    entry.file(gotFile, fail);

    function gotFile(file) {
        that.readAsText(file);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        // should be forwarded to caller somehow
    }
}-*/
```